# How to display values entered via a TextBox in a GridView on button-click without saving the data to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, web-applications

I have created two TextBoxes to enter the FirstName and LastName of an employee and a button in a web-based ASP.NET application using C# on Visual studio 2010.when I click on the button , the values that I enter in the TextBoxes should be displayed in a Gridview without being stored in the database.

How can I do that? Can you provide a sample code to execute the above mentioned functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working code..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("FIRST NAME");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("LAST NAME");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
DataTable dt;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = TextBox1.Text;
    dr1[1] = TextBox2.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1); 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access gridview in code like that:

```
var gridview = document.getElementById("<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>");
```

After you can access in that gridview will be methods to **renew/add/delete** information in client side. But notice, that you also have to tell your server-side that you renewed the information in DB, so he can save changes to DB.
I expect that you should send **ajax** request for renewing data in DB, and use the code to access grid from **javascript** and renew data in client-side over **javascript**.

Answer (score 0):

Take the values which you have entered in textbox in a **DataTable** and the give that dataTable as a **datasource** to that **datagrid**.
Check this link
http://forums.asp.net/t/1672122.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

the code you provided works fine. but it will add only one record to GridView. If you added a new record then the old data will be replaced. So we have to preserve the old record.

Just enter the below code to the button click event.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["Data"] == null) //Checking if the session contain any value.
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //creating the columns.
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("Stock");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //Create a new row and add the row values.
            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; //Populate values to Gridview.
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Session["Data"] = dt; //Storing that table into session.           
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"]; //Retrieve the stored table from session.

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //Adding a new row to existing table.
            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; //Populate new table values to Gridview.
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Session.Remove("Data"); //Clear the session.
            Session["Data"] = dt; //Store the new table to the session.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int id = 0;

 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, 
                                               DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
  int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;

id= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).